# Identify a specific class element within another div

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a series of photos on a page, which have below them some text information and some buttons:

```
<div class="photowrapper">
 <div class="photowrapperphoto">
  <div class="photocontainer">image</div>
  </div>
 <div class="textwrapperphoto">
  <div class="textleftwrapperphoto">
   <div class="phototitle">photo_0001</div>
   <div class="photoprice">&pound;3.00</div>
   <div class="photosize">6 by 4 inch</div>
 </div>
 <div class="textrightwrapperphoto">
  <div class="photoaddbutton">Add</div>
  <div class="photoremovebutton">Delete</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to put in some jquery so that when someone clicks on the 'photoaddbutton', it amends the class of 'photowrapperphoto' (to add a background color).

I can't seem to figure out how to identify the element photowrapperphoto.

I have loads of the above html (i.e. loads of images) on the page.  I just want the immediately preceeding 'photowrapperphoto' to change, but at the moment the jquery I'm using changes all 'photowrapperphoto' classes on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.photoaddbutton').click(function() {
  $('.photowrapperphoto').attr('class', 'photowrapperphotoselected');
 });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend getting familiar with jQuery's awesome [DOM traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you let the `photowrapperphoto` items keep their `photowrapperphoto` class, and add an additional class `selected`, instead of changing the class.

The javascript to modify the correct `photowrapperphoto` could be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photoaddbutton').click(function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('.photowrapper')   // go up in the DOM until .photowrapper
            .children('.photowrapperphoto') // go down one level to .photowrapperphoto 
            .addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

To specify a special style for the selected `photowrapperphoto`, you can use a rule like this in your CSS:

```
.photowrapperphoto.selected
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: +1 My answer was nearly the same as yours, but I think you stated it better.  I did spend some time on a nice [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je8HV/1/) though.  Feel free to add it to your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Am fairly new to jquery so was having trouble navigating the DOM - really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.photoaddbutton').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.photowrapper').find('.photowrapperphoto').prop('class', 'photowrapperphotoselected');
   });
});
```

But I recommend adding and removing a class, not replacing one by the other. The first class marks the generic role of the element, the second one marks it's additional role when present.